# create multiple files from single text file based on headings

Tags: python, regex, sed, markdown

I have what I think is a really simple problem to solve (preferably with OS X / *nix terminal tools rather than windows command line).

I have a manuscript formatted in markdown with # (H1) denoting a chapter heading. 
I would like to break this large file up into smaller chapter files as I'll later be converting the manuscript to epub / mobi with pandoc. This separate-file-per-chapter format is the the recommended format according to the pandoc docs (http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/epub.html ) and also makes the editing process a little less unwieldy. Interestingly it is similar to what some other projects have done e.g. https://github.com/visionmedia/masteringnode

I was thinking that this would be possible with a simple python script or using something like sed but I just don't know where to start. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the `csplit` tool.

Comment: What is it? What does it do? Where can we find it?

Comment: here are [some examples](http://www.sanfoundry.com/5-practical-csplit-command-usage-examples-in-linux/) found by doing a [simple google](https://www.google.com/search?q=csplit) where you can find more details